# Approximating an exponential function with another function

Tags: functions, approximation

I have a function $f(\ell)=\exp\Big(-{\frac{a}{\ell b+c}}\Big)$. I would like to rewrite this function in the form $(1-d)g^{\ell}$.

How can I express $g$ and $d$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Here, a,b,c are constant real numbers.

Comment: Your question is not fully clear to me, you have four different variables as arguments to the exponential function in the R.H.S, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $l$, but a single variable $x$ in the L.H.S., I don't get it, what are those variables, real numbers, or complex ones? Functions of $x$? Please clarify.

Comment: @Arc I edited the question to give more clarity.

Comment: Remember that a function $e^{-x}$ has a series expansion at $x=0$ in the form $e^{-x} = 1 -x + x^2/2 - x^3/6 + \dots$, are you looking for an exact solution, or just an approximate one?

Comment: @Arc I am looking for an approximate solution as an exact solution  is not possible.

Comment: $e^{-1/l}$ and $g^l$ are too dissimilar in form, check these examples [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-1%2F%28x%2B1%29%29) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5Ex), so it depends strongly on the points where you are taking the expansion, and even so your approximation may be very limited in accuracy.